# best way to configure memcache for session?

Tags: session, servlets, memcached

I found lots of information on how to configure memcached to store sessions, most of them state the following steps:

```
1. download some jars and put under TOMCAT/lib/
2. add some codes to content.xml like
<Context>
  ...
  <Manager className="de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager"
    memcachedNodes="n1:host1.yourdomain.com:11211,n2:host2.yourdomain.com:11211"
    failoverNodes="n1"
    requestUriIgnorePattern=".*\.(ico|png|gif|jpg|css|js)$"
    transcoderFactoryClass="de.javakaffee.web.msm.serializer.kryo.KryoTranscoderFactory"
    />
</Context>
```

However, I do not quite understand this method. I have set up a memcached server and a servlet to write to it using

```
MemcachedClient c = new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(),
            AddrUtil.getAddresses("192.168.56.128:11211"));
c.set("someKey", 3600, "hi").get();
```

Everything works fine. However, I can safely remove `<Manager>...</>` without making any difference.

So I am wondering what is the purpose of `<Manager>...</>`? Or how does the servlet react to it?